# Read and write Serial data simultaneously in Arduino

Tags: java, arduino, serial-port, serial-communication

First of all, I am newbie to Arduino. I have created a Java app that communicates with Arduino through Serial successfully. But what I want to do is read data from gyro sensor and monitor that data in java, and send command from java to control motors. Is there a way to read data and send command simultaneously without data collision?
I use Arduino mega 2560 board.

```
void loop( ){
    while(Serial.available( ){
        char command = Serial.read();
        switch(command){
            case 'w': 
                // run motors
                // lots of other cases
            default: 
                //when there is no command received and the last data is send at leat 1s ago, send data
                //I afraid data collide when there is incoming command during sending data
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry, for my bad english.

Comment: You just need to work with two mode. An for send/recieve command and another for send/recieve data. When you have data from gyro to send, send it if Serial is available and wait for command. In Java, inverse.

Answer (score 0):

Because there are 2 wires connecting the Arduino to the PC, a "collision" is not possible.  When the PC sends to the Arduino, it uses the Arduino RX wire.  When the Arduino sends to the PC, it uses the Arduino TX wire.  This is [Full duplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duplex_(telecommunications)#Full-duplex) communication.